# wc command issue

Tags: wc

I have only one row in my file. When I execute `wc -c file1.txt` the result is 200, while the output of `wc -L file1.txt` is 198. What explains the difference of 2?

Answer (score 5):

`-L` prints the length of the longest line.  Your line must be 198 characters long.  The two missing bytes are end of line and end of file characters.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your quick reply. I got your point. but do we have any option to set both results should be same for wc -c and wc -L. am i missing anything here.?

Comment: The two options are meant to provide different information.  So, no, you cannot have the two give same result.

Comment: Thank you both. the file which i shown is being loaded from one process(target). if i want to add/include end of line and end of file charector in the output file what should i do?. Any Idea

Comment: @abhilash Your question essentially was why the output of two different options to the `wc` program were different. I think that question has been answered. If you have another question, post another separately. This is not a discussion board.

Comment: There is no character that represents "end of file". All you can safely say is that at least one is LF (newline) and that it follows 198 printable characters

Comment: Sorry to dragging bit much on this . thanks all for your kind reply. cheers.